# Removing duplicates for ML training set?

Tags: machine-learning, duplicates, data-fitting

I am wondering what is the common practice (if there is any) for handling duplicate observations for machine learning training sets.

Dropping duplicate observations would surely speed up the computations so that's a benefit.

But would it not throw the model off by simplifying it? Do models take the number of duplicates into account? I have a feeling it depends on the model, but am not able to find a clear answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can imagine this differing very much for your specific use case, your data, and the type of models you use.

Many models would tend towards getting a certain record right if there are many duplicates of a that record: whether it's the C4.5 algorithm behind many decision trees, or the stochastic gradient descent behind neural networks.

Removing duplicates could be a very legitimate thing to do if you learn that the duplicates are a result of faulty training data, because in that case you'd want to modify your data to represent the real world as accurately as possible.
Though if the nature of your data is just that many records are identical, but they're still legitimate data points, then for many applications you'd want your model to weigh those data points appropriately, because in the end, that's what your real-world data would look like as well.